# Hide passwords inside a standard table cell

Tags: html, css, web

I'm working on a password manager and i need to display the password on a table, is there any way to hide the password? I'll put a button to toggle the visibility of the password.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello @Panza Ghor write some code so we can help you.

Comment: "Hide" *from whom?* It must be in the HTML, so it's only hidden unless you bother to actually look. If you just want to hide it visually, there are any number of ways to do so.

Comment: I'm making the HTML/CSS part of the project so i had to prepare a presentation for a meeting today, another team is going to integrate it with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bit of javascript - this example uses the jQuery javascript library, so you just need to include a script tag that points to the library *(as shown below in the HTML)*.

```js
$('#passTD').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css('color','blue');
});
$('#passTD').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).css('color','transparent');
});
```

```css
td{padding:5px;border:1px solid #ccc;}

#passTD{color:transparent;cursor:default;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><div id='passTD'>MyDogIsSam</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Keep in mind, though, that the password is visible to anyone using DevTools (F12) - for example, right-click on the password field and choose `Inspect element`.

However, if you are displaying the password via `mouseover`, then presumably that person is allowed to see the password and you are only hiding it from someone casually peeking over the user's shoulder.

Another option, for improved security, is to store the password in a MySQL database table, and then use AJAX to request the password. This a bit more advanced, but there are many YouTube tutorials that cover how to create a login system using PHP and AJAX.

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript to toggle password,

**Example:**

```
 <!-- Password field -->
Password: <input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput">

<!-- An element to toggle between password visibility -->
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password
```

**Add JavaScript:**

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
if (x.type === "password") {
 x.type = "text";
} else {
x.type = "password";
}
}
```

Comment: Looks familiar ;)  ....https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_password.asp